# $p|\Phi_n(2)$ then $p|\Phi_{pn}(2)$

Tags: abstract-algebra, cyclotomic-polynomials

> Prove that $p|\Phi_n(2)$ then $p|\Phi_{pn}(2)$

Here $\Phi_n(x)$ is nth cyclotomic polynomial.

I don't know what I should use. $$\Phi_n(x)=\prod_{{1\leq a\leq n } \& {(a,n)=1}}(x-\zeta_n^a) $$ or $$\Phi_n(x)=\prod_{d|n}(x^{n/d}-1)^{\mu(d)}$$

Comment: Does $p$ divide $n$?

Comment: @lhf there is no such assumption. I think we should divide the case when $p|n$ and $p \not|n$

Comment: @user45765 I think it is not true. For example, $\Phi_2(x)=x+1$ but $\Phi_6(x)=x^2-x+1$ and $\Phi_2(x)\not| \Phi_6(x)$. Furthermore, $\zeta_{pn}^a$ is not equal to $\zeta_n^a$ and $(pa,pn)=p$.

Comment: Ah, my bad. However for $p\nmid n$, you will have $\zeta_n^a$ showing up by CRT.

Comment: @user45765 I can't understand... Could you explain it in detail?

Comment: @Pearl $\zeta_{np}^a$ shows up if $a\in Z_{np}^\star$. However CRT says $Z_{np}^\star\cong Z_p^\star\times Z_n^\star$ if $(n,p)=1$. If $p\mid n$, you can consider $n=p^km$ with $(p,m)=1$ and apply the trick as before.

Answer (score 1):

Observe that the map $(-)^p:\mathbb F_p[x]\to \mathbb F_p[x]$ is ring morphism (with trivial kernel). For any positive integer $m$ indivisible by prime $p$ and nonnegative integer $k$ one has $$\begin{align*}\Phi_{p^km}(x)&=_{\mathbb F_p[x]}\prod_{d\mid p^km}\left(x^{p^km/d}-1\right)^{\mu(d)}\\ &=_{\mathbb F_p[x]}\prod_{d\mid m}\left(\left(x^{p^km/d}-1\right)\left(x^{p^{k-1}m/d}-1\right)^{-1}\right)^{\mu(d)}\\ &=_{\mathbb F_p[x]}\prod_{d\mid m}\left(\left(x^{m/d}-1\right)^{p^k-p^{k-1}}\right)^{\mu(d)}\\ &=_{\mathbb F_p[x]}\left(\prod_{d\mid m} (x^{m/d}-1)^{\mu(d)}\right)^{p^k-p^{k-1}}=_{\mathbb F_p[x]} \Phi_{m}(x)^{p^k-p^{k-1}}\end{align*}$$ From which it follows that $$\Phi_n(2)=_{\mathbb F_p}0\implies \Phi_{n/\gcd(n,p^\infty)}(2)=_{\mathbb F_p}0\implies \Phi_{pn}(2)=_{\mathbb F_p}0$$ Where $\gcd(n,p^\infty)$ is a shorthand for the largest power of $p$ dividing $n$ $\blacksquare$